# Strapi App Deployment Failed After Migrating DB on Railway

Tags: postgresql, strapi, railway

I Just migrated my PostgreSQL database as requested by Railway. But now my Strapi app fails to deploy with the following error:

```
#10 23.36 error @strapi/plugin-i18n@4.11.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14.19.1 <=18.x.x". Got "21.1.0"
#10 23.37 error Found incompatible module.
#10 23.37 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
#10 ERROR: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c yarn install --frozen-lockfile" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
-----
> [stage-0  6/10] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/559dccd6-41e7-4675-9191-92a31f131886-/usr/local/share/cache/yarn/v6,target=/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6 yarn install --frozen-lockfile:
1.310 yarn install v1.22.21
1.392 warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies caused by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
1.396 [1/5] Validating package.json...
1.398 [2/5] Resolving packages...
1.826 (node:1) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
1.826 (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
2.181 [3/5] Fetching packages...
23.36 error @strapi/plugin-i18n@4.11.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14.19.1 <=18.x.x". Got "21.1.0"
23.37 error Found incompatible module.
23.37 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
-----
Dockerfile:20
-------------------
18 | ENV NIXPACKS_PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$NIXPACKS_PATH
19 | COPY . /app/.
20 | >>> RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/559dccd6-41e7-4675-9191-92a31f131886-/usr/local/share/cache/yarn/v6,target=/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6 yarn install --frozen-lockfile
21 |
22 | # build phase
-------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c yarn install --frozen-lockfile" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
Error: Docker build failed
```

When i remove remove package-lock.json I have the following error:

```
#10 2.031 error @strapi/plugin-i18n@4.11.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14.19.1 <=18.x.x". Got "21.1.0"
#10 2.042 error Found incompatible module.
#10 2.042 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
#10 ERROR: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c yarn install --frozen-lockfile" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
-----
> [stage-0  6/10] RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/559dccd6-41e7-4675-9191-92a31f131886-/usr/local/share/cache/yarn/v6,target=/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6 yarn install --frozen-lockfile:
0.630 yarn install v1.22.21
0.709 [1/5] Validating package.json...
0.711 [2/5] Resolving packages...
1.097 (node:1) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
1.097 (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
1.429 [3/5] Fetching packages...
2.031 error @strapi/plugin-i18n@4.11.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=14.19.1 <=18.x.x". Got "21.1.0"
2.042 error Found incompatible module.
2.042 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
-----
Dockerfile:20
-------------------
18 | ENV NIXPACKS_PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$NIXPACKS_PATH
19 | COPY . /app/.
20 | >>> RUN --mount=type=cache,id=s/559dccd6-41e7-4675-9191-92a31f131886-/usr/local/share/cache/yarn/v6,target=/usr/local/share/.cache/yarn/v6 yarn install --frozen-lockfile
21 |
22 | # build phase
-------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c yarn install --frozen-lockfile" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
Error: Docker build failed
```

And when I remove package.json and keep only package-lock.json the deployment works but I can't access my strapi app anymore as it gives me a 403 error

King regards

Vincent Abensour